# How to find the root cause for Spark job aborts with Cassandra (that leads to ClassCastException - ShuffleMapTask to Task)?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to read data from Cassandra using Spark.

```
    DataFrame rdf = sqlContext.read().option("keyspace", "readypulse")
            .option("table", "ig_posts")
            .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").load();

    rdf.registerTempTable("cassandra_table");
    System.out.println(sqlContext.sql("select count(external_id) from cassandra_table").collect()[0].getLong(0));
```

The task fails with the following error. I am not able to understand why the ShuffleMaptask is being called and why it is a problem to cast it to Task.

```
16/03/30 02:27:15 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, ip-10-165-180-22.ec2.internal): 
            java.lang.ClassCastException: 
            org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask 
                cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task
                        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:193)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/03/30 02:27:15 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) on executor ip-10-165-180-22.ec2.internal: 
            java.lang.ClassCastException (org.apache.spark.scheduler.Shuf
                fleMapTask 
            cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task) [duplicate 1]

16/03/30 02:27:15 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
```

I am using EMR 4.4, Spark 1.6, Cassandra 2.2 (Datastax Community), and spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10 1.6.0-M1 (also tried 1.5.0)

I also tried the same with following code, but got same error.

```
    CassandraJavaRDD<CassandraRow> cjrdd = functions.cassandraTable(
            KEYSPACE, tableName).select(columns);
    logger.info("Got rows from cassandra " + cjrdd.count());

    JavaRDD<Double> jrdd2 = cjrdd.map(new Function<CassandraRow, Double>() {
        @Override
        public Double call(CassandraRow trainingRow) throws Exception {
            Object fCount = trainingRow.getRaw("follower_count");
            double count = 0;
            if (fCount != null) {
                count = (Long) fCount;
            }
            return count;
        }
    });
    logger.info("Mapper done : " + jrdd2.count());
    logger.info("Mapper done values : " + jrdd2.collect());
```

Comment: Have you sorted it out? What was the real cause(s) of the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've been encountering the similar problem recently due to
`--conf spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true`.

Quoting [Spark's official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment):

> **spark.executor.userClassPathFirst** (Experimental) Same functionality as `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst`, but applied to executor instances.

I think those exceptions were due to some jar version conflict, and by the spark document, "The user's jar should never include Hadoop or Spark libraries, however, these will be added at runtime."

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with the same error. But setting userClassPathFirst=true doesn't help me. I set "spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=false" and "spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=false". It solved my ClassCastException problem. Here is my command.

spark-submit --conf "spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=false" --conf "spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=false" --deploy-mode client --class org.sdrc.kspmis.dashboardservice.KspDashboardServiceApplication --master spark://192.168.1.95:7077 dashboard-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar